# Laravel Queues - why is Queue job retrying every 3 seconds, if I specify timeout=5 and expire=>7?

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to set up my queue worker in Laravel 5.3 and am trying to ensure that I fully understand nuances of the interrelated parameters `expire`, `--tries`, `--timeout`, because **the results I am seeing suggest I am not understanding something**.

Note: In the Laravel 5.3 documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#introduction), it refers to `retry_after` as being a parameter for the database queue connection type, but in my installation of Laravel 5.3, that parameter seems to be `expire`.

In any case, I have a job, let's call it `SendReminder`. I purposefully added a line of code that causes an error, so I can test the functioning of the queue tries/retries and eventual labeling of the job as failed in the `failed_jobs` table.

Here is my database queue config in `queue.php`:

```
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table'  => 'jobs',
            'queue'  => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 7,
            'expire' => 7,
        ],
```

For testing, I want to let it try 3 times before being sent to `failed_jobs` table.

I expect the job to take not more than 5 seconds, and so setting `--timeout=5`, and `expire` to 7 (or `retry_after` to 7), would seem to be in line with the Queue documentation, which says "The --timeout value should always be at least several seconds shorter than your retry_after configuration value. This will ensure that a worker processing a given job is always killed before the job is retried."

**Based on above, I expect the job to be considered failed after 21 seconds.**

After running `php artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=email,default --timeout=5 --tries=3` and then dispatching the job via `php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

I count with my stopwatch 9 seconds until the queue worker displays

```
[2021-09-02 14:22:14] Failed: App\Jobs\PrepareSendReminderJob
```

and in my Laravel log I see

```
[2021-09-02 14:22:08] local.ERROR: ErrorException:
[2021-09-02 14:22:11] local.ERROR: ErrorException:
[2021-09-02 14:22:14] local.ERROR: ErrorException:
```

This doesn't seem to make sense. I would expect, based on my `expire` being set to 7, that the failure message would only come 21 seconds after the job is dispatched and immediately picked up by the queue. And I get same result every time - 3 seconds between each error message in the log.

Can someone explain why I am seeing this result?

Thanks!

-- Edit:
And here is the job class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Log;

class SendReminderJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    //public function __construct(\App\Services\SearchService $searchService)
    public function __construct()
    {
       
        $this->queue = 'email';
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       // nothing here for now, except for this line to cause an error on purpose
      Log::infoo('text');        

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you overwrite the retry time in your class? Can you add the job class to the question please?

Comment: I think this explains why I am not understanding: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13932. I guess I need to use `sleep` to specify the in between failed attempts time.